# how to convert bytes MD5 in java to php

Tags: java, php

How do I convert this Java code to PHP?

```
public static String encryptMD5_Salt(String content) {
    String resultString = "";
    String appkey = "acdf,kef";

    byte[] a = appkey.getBytes();
    byte[] datSource = content.getBytes();
    byte[] b = new byte[a.length + 4 + datSource.length];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < datSource.length; i++) {
        b[i] = datSource[i];
    }

    b[i++] = (byte) 143;
    b[i++] = (byte) 112;
    b[i++] = (byte) 131;
    b[i++] = (byte) 143;

    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        b[i] = a[k];
        i++;
    }

    try {
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md5.update(b);
        resultString = new HexBinaryAdapter().marshal(md5.digest());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultString.toLowerCase();
}
```

The problem is that I can't find the equivalent way to convert `Integer` to `byte` in java:

```
b[i++] = (byte) 143;
b[i++] = (byte) 112;
b[i++] = (byte) 131;
b[i++] = (byte) 143;
```

the php codes:

```
$hexString = '123456';#sample value
$bkey = pack('a*',$hexString);
$bkey .= pack('N*',143,112,131,143);
$bkey = pack('a*','acdf,kef');
$re  = md5($bkey);
$re =sha1('sha256',$re);
```

and they get difference result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little messy, but:

```
$int_val = 143
$byte_val = (($int_val + 129) % 256) - 128
```

But note that PHP has no equivalent `byte` type, so this is really just an integer represented in a similar way.

Comment: and how to use md5 with bytes in php?